# how to define webservice methods with optional and mandatory parameters information

Tags: web-services, jakarta-ee, jax-ws

I want to define webservice methods(operation) with optional and mandatory parameters information. So that i can generate xsd file having information whether a parameter for a particular operation is optional or mandatory.

Comment: Different implementations with different signatures ?

Comment: I don't think JAXB supports xsd validation customization (`minOccurs` etc), you can add `@SchemaValidation` to your service implementation bean to validate against an existing (or hand-made) xsd

Answer (score 0):

You could define an own object for all your parameters. Some of this parameters are mandatory, some are not. By defining this own object as a JAXB class, you are done. The sent XML by SOAP will only contain the non mandatory data if they exist.